# Como dejar el menu de opciones diferente de acuerdo al perfil

Tags: php, mysql

Cuál sería el código para que de acuerdo al perfil del usuario, puedan o no acceder a una opción en el menú.

Tengo la tabla perfil `1-admin`, `2-secretaria` y `3-gestionhumana`.

iniciarsesion.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
extract ($_POST);
require "../Modelo/conexionBasesDatos.php";
/* los variables que viene del formulario son: $login, $password */

/*asigno a la variable password el valor encriptado de lo que colocaron
en el password del formulario, ya que así esta en la base de datos */

$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
$login = $_POST['login'];

$objConexion=Conectarse();
// Vamos a realizar el proceso para consultar los pacientes
//Guardamos en una variable la sentencia sql
$sql="select * from tblusuarios where idUsuario = '$login' and usuPassword = '$pass'";
//Asignar a una variable el resultado de la consulta
$resultado=$objConexion->query($sql);
//verifico si existe el usuario
$existe = $resultado->num_rows;

if ($existe==1)   //quiere decir que los datos estan bien
{
 $usuario=$resultado->fetch_object() or die ("Error");
 $_SESSION['user']= $usuario->idUsuario; 
 header("location:../Vista/index2.php?pag=contenido");
 
}
else 
{
 header("location:../Vista/index2.php?pag=iniciarSesion&x=1");  //x=1, quiere decir que el usuario no esta registrado
}




?>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses un condicional, en el cual le puedes indicar si es el usuario es `nivel 1`, puede ver x menú, si es `nivel 2`, puede ver otro y así.

Comment: podrias decirme como seria la sintaxis del codigo

Comment: Sabes programar en php?, la pregunta que te hago no es para ofender, si no para ayudarte. También en necesario saber si en la tabla ya tienes definidos los niveles de usuario, por ejemplo: 1, 2 y 3. Tu preguntas cual seria el código, pero si has hecho algo, por favor compártelo.

Comment: no tranquilo, yo tengo la tabla usuarios y tabla perfil estos están enumerados y con su respectivo nombre

Comment: Bueno, perfecto, entonces lo que puede hacer es un crear tres tipo de menu y llamarlos segun el nivel de usuario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a darte un ejemplo de como puedes hacerlo.
Lo que hice fue crear dos tipos de menú.

menuAdmin.php

```
<p>Menu admin</p>
<p>
<a href="">Ver listado</a>
<a href="">Borrar usuarios</a>
</p>
```

menuUser.php

```
<p>Menu usuario</p>
<p>
<a href="">Ver listado</a>
</p>
```

En el index.php hago lo siguiente

```
<?php
$usuarioNivel = 1;

if($usuarioNivel == 1) {
    include 'menuAdmin.php';
    } else {
        include 'menuUser.php';
}
?>
```

Uso un condicional para decir que si el nivel de usuario es igual a `1`, me incluya el menú admin, de lo contrario me incluirá el menú de usuario.
Como resultado voy a obtener el menú Admin, claro.

Lo que tu tienes que hacer es reemplazar los datos de la variable `$usuarioNivel` que la vas a traer desde la base de datos.

Esta es una manera de hacerlo, puede haber muchas mas. Esto es en modo de ejemplo para orientarte. Después tu puede usar funciones o lo que creas adecuado para tu app.

Answer (score 1):

Debes de crear una función de inicio de sesión, en la que definas qué menú o plantilla podrá ver el usuario; además podrías definir con la función los cierres de sesión y que no se pueda visualizar una plantilla sin iniciar sesión antes. Con PHP es una forma fácil de hacerlo.

Valida algún dato de las tablas... por ejemplo que aparezca cierta plantilla o menú a un usuario solo si cierto campo del registro tiene cierto dato.

Puedes agregar condicionales a tu código...
por ejemplo:

```
if ($tipoUsuario == 1){
## código HTML de la plantilla o menú ##
}
```

La variable `$tipoUsuario` debe de traer un valor de la base de datos por medio de sentencias SQL, y según esta variable aparece el menú o plantilla.

Comment: favor de revisar [answer] esto es mas un comentario que una respuesta

Comment: comparto lo que dice @shadow